# Converting string into byte

Tags: vb.net, string, winforms, type-conversion

How do i turn this string into binary without going through the decimal number system first.
So I have.

```
Dim test as string = "11111111"
' And a text field called mask1
mask1.text = Convert.ToByte(m1)
' Then i get an overflow exception everytime
```

Comment: What is `m1`? Did you mean to pass the string `test` into `Convert.ToByte`?

Comment: I think the string is a representation of a Byte number in binary number format and he wants to convert this into an actual number (in this case 256). @user: your code tries to assign the number 11111111 (11 million) to a byte variable that goes from 0 to 255, that's what causes the exception at least.

Answer (score 2):

You appear to have forgotten to use the number base in the [Convert.ToByte](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/c7xhf79k%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method:

```
Dim s As String = "11111111"
Dim b As Byte = Convert.ToByte(s, 2)
Console.WriteLine(b) ' outputs "255"
```